# Unity samsung galaxy s2 lag spike on first touch

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing a huge lag spike on the Samsung galaxy s2 when I click on the button. This happens only on the first touch after that it's buttery smooth.

I have also tested on my Huawei p9 lite and it runs just fine without any lag spike.

Then I thought that something is wrong with my game so I have tested this on an empty scene with only a single canvas and one button and this issue was still present.

The profiler shows that Event.SystemUpdate is the culprit:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: This is a know bug. Are you using a custom font anywhere in your UI?

Comment: Nope i'm using the default one.

Comment: Remove `StandaloneInputModule` and see what happens...

Comment: @Programmer Once StandAloneInputModule is removed buttons  no longer work (Obviously) and the lag spike is no more. So seems that you are correct this is a bug.

Comment: What if you remove it then attach it from code?

Comment: Tried to add that component via script still same lag spike.

Comment: File for a bug report. I am sure this has been done before but sometimes you have to remind them that this issue is still there. Maybe simulating a click event in the `Start` function(as first click) may solve this as a workaround. I am not sure but you should try that.

Comment: Alright thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But in my case, it was a call to DateTime.Now somewhere deep in the methods that was slow!
take a look at this:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-il2cpp-system-dot-datetime-dot-now-is-slow-on-the-first-run
I replaced the code with Time.time and it's fixed now.